# How To Use do_shortcode with WooCommerce One Page Checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, onepage-checkout

I'm trying to use the WordPress `do_shortcode` function for the WooCommerce One Page Checkout Plugin which uses shortcode like this: `[woocommerce_one_page_checkout template="product-table" product_ids="product, ids, here"]`. It seems like I can only use this shortcode IF it's in the content editor and won't allow me to add this to a page template using the `do_shortcode` function.

Their documentation [here](https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-one-page-checkout/#can-i-display-the-one-page-checkout-shortcode-using-the-do-shortcode-function) says:

> If you wish to display the One Page Checkout Shortcode using WordPress’ do_shortcode() function instead of including the shortcode in a post or page’s content, you will also need to attach custom code to the 'is_wcopc_checkout' filter and make sure a boolean true value is returned.

So I tried adding the following to the functions.php file:

`add_filter( 'is_wcopc_checkout', function(){ return true; } );`

and it didn't seem to do the trick.

I also tried:

```
add_filter( 'is_wcopc_checkout', 'my_one_page_checkout' );
function my_one_page_checkout(){
  return true;
}
add_filter( 'is_wcopc_checkout', 'true' );
```

That didn't seem to do it either.

Am I adding this code to the functions.php wrong? Any help on how I can get the One Page Checkout Plugin to work using `do_shortcode`?

Here's my full code in the page template for reference:

```
<?php 
echo do_shortcode('[woocommerce_one_page_checkout template="product-table" product_ids="62, 122, 438, 52, 433, 435, 512, 514"]');
?>
```

Thanks for your help.

(I tried contacting WooCommerce support and they were no help saying that this is custom code and they can't do anything to help.)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to return a true to a filter is like sitting the call back to WP default `__return_true`. So the function will be like

```
add_filter( 'is_wcopc_checkout', '__return_true' );
```

There is no filter named `is_wcopc_checkout` in the code of WooCommerce one page checkout version 1.0.2

From their doc- You can also manually add a shortcode `[woocommerce_one_page_checkout]` to any page or post and use the shortcode's attributes.

Usage: `[woocommerce_one_page_checkout product_ids="30,45,12"]`

**Some context from One page checkout readme.**

To register your template, attach a callback to the `'wcopc_templates'` filter and add a new array of your template's details to the `$templates` array passed to your function.

For example, to register a custom pricing table template, the code would be similar to:

```
function eg_add_opc_template( $templates ) {

    $templates['my-custom-pricing-table'] = array(
        'label'       => __( 'My Pricing Table', 'eg' ),
        'description' => __( "Display a sophisticated and colourful pricing table with each product's attributes, but not weight or dimensions.", 'eg' ),
    );

    return $templates;
}
add_filter( 'wcopc_templates', 'eg_add_opc_template' ) );
```

The key used in the `$templates` array should be the template's file name (excluding the extension). The `label` element of the array is the name displayed on the One Page Checkout dialog. The `description` element is used for the tooltip next to the template's name.

Comment: If there is no filter, why do they suggest to use that `is_wcopc_checkout` so we can use the shortcode with do_shortcode.

Yes, I'm aware of that shortcode, the issue is that shortcode ONLY works if it's in the content of a page. It does NOT work if you use it in a template using the `do_shortcode` function as I mentioned. The goal is that I'm trying to be able to use that shortcode in a page template using the `do_shortcode` function. 

So I'm afraid this answer so far still doesn't help.

Comment: @Jason You may try the updated answer section under - Some context from One page checkout readme.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I saw that on the documentation, and that would be if we wanted to add a custom pricing table template, etc. I'm not trying to add a custom template, so it's not relevant. My quest is simple, I just want to be able to use their shortcode (i.e. `[woocommerce_one_page_checkout]`) on my own template pages using the `do_shortcode` function.